# Can you have if conditions on INSERT statement - e.g. only INSERT if a > b?

Tags: sql, validation, if-statement, sql-insert

So I know I could obviously check the conditions using another language like PHP then only insert if the conditions matched, but is there a way to do this in pure SQL? I guess I could create a VIEW with this condition, but let's say I effectively have the table Event(EventID, StartDate, EndDate), is there a way I could have SQL only insert the data if EndDate > StartDate? If not, then return an error. I guess the logic would be something like the following, though obviously it wouldn't work...

```
INSERT INTO Event(EventID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES(1, 01/01/2016, 02/02/2016) WHERE EndDate > StartDate
```

Soooooo...is anything like that possible using purely SQL?

Comment: Since you are not stating which DBMS you are using, I'm giving you here an ANSI style answer: Check the use of `CASE` clause in SQL language (much like `IF`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can use check constraint for it. Somewhat Like below

```
Alter date _ column add constant const_name Check( value>Get date()).
```

Or if you can't change your schema then you can use sql stored procedure for inserting and checking this condition.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the database to guarantee that the data is correct, then you want a `check` constraint:

```
alter table event
    add constraint chk_startdate_enddate check (startdate < enddate);
```

Not all databases support check constraints (although they are standard SQL), so you might need to use a trigger instead.

If you just want to validate at the application level, then use `insert . . . select`.  Typical syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO Event(EventID, StartDate, EndDate) 
    SELECT EventID, StartDate, EndDate
    FROM (SELECT 1 as EventId, '2016-01-01' as StartDate, '2016-02-02' as EndDate
         ) x
    WHERE EndDate > StartDate;
```

Note:  Some databases would require a `FROM` clause in the subquery, such as `FROM dual`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I think the first solution shold work for me, though if not, I guess the 2nd. I will try it later. Cheers!